# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_9_input to have shape (64, 64, 3) but got array with shape (32, 32, 1)

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

CATEGORIES = ["Dog", "Cat"]  # will use this to convert prediction num to string value


def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = 32  # 50 in txt-based
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # read in the image, convert to grayscale
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))  # resize image to match model's expected sizing
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)  # return the image with shaping that TF wants.

import pickle 

with open ('module','rb') as f:
     model=pickle.load(f)

prediction = model.predict([prepare('dog.5000.jpg')])
print(prediction)  # will be a list in a list.
print(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][0])])
```

When i execute this code  `prediction =model.predict([prepare('dog.5000.jpg')])` I got the error ValueError:

> Error when checking input: expected conv2d_9_input to have shape (64,
>   64, 3) but got array with shape (32, 32, 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to understand that your network excepts a 64x64 image, not a 32x32 image, change your

`IMG_SIZE` variable to be `64` not `32`

Secondly, the network excepts that input image to be colored not grayscale, hence the number of channels should be 3, not 1, for that remove

`cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` from this line
`img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`

In summary, this is your new prepare_image function

```
def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = 64
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
IMG_SIZE = 32
new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
```

for this:

```
IMG_SIZE = 64
new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
```

Comment: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4096 into shape (64,64,3)

Comment: this will also give error, follow my answer below to solve your problem

Comment: Yes, follow Imtinan answer. I didnt see you convert grayscale

Comment: yes when i change in the code i received this error message